Does encrypting a virus / malware renders it inactive?
Phrased differently, can an encrypted malware still act ? Not encrypted by design, but after the fact.
And can it still be detected by an antivirus when in encrypted form ? (Given it is in decrypted form)

This question might be better on https://security.stackexchange.com/

It would not be able to execute.  It would need to be decrypted first.
It would probably not be picked up by an anti-virus as the signature would not match the know signature, and the anti-virus would not be able to decrypt it.
